# Securely establish and verify PIN over network

Tags: tls, brute-force, pbkdf2

Is there a (relatively simple) protocol for setting up a (6-digit) PIN on a remote server, that also prevents those, who may get a DB dump from the server, from brute-forcing that PIN?

Is PBKDF2 and key transfer via TLS 1.2 good enough a solution?
Or is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: Only if combined with sufficient lockout mechanisms, e.g. 3 wrong attempts blocks access for 15 minutes, 3 more blocks for 2 hours, ...

Comment: *"... that also prevents those in control of a server from brute-forcing that PIN? ..."* - why should anybody __in control of the server__ brute force the PIN? It could just change the server side code and log the PIN entered by the user directly.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain the broader picture. It is likely not the ultimate goal of an attacker to guess the PIN but to access resources which should be restricted to someone knowing the PIN. Especially if somebody is in control of the server (as you assume) one might even skip this verification step completely and directly access the protected resource without PIN, i.e. it does not even matter how good the PIN itself is protected.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, by "those in control" I meant e. g. an administrator, who can't disable the validation altogether, but instead can dump PIN hashes from the DB and run brute-force attacks against them.

Answer (score 8):

> that also prevents those in control of a server from brute-forcing
> that PIN?

Essentially, no.  No matter how securely it is set, or how strong the hash format is, once the server operators have a 6-digit hashed value they can brute-force it reasonably quickly.  The short and predictable length of the PIN make it susceptible to brute-force attacks.  You don't mention if it's numeric or alpha-numeric, but either is trivially forcible at a length of 6.

> Is PBKDF2 and key transfer via TLS 1.2 good enough a solution?

Those are good solutions for hashing and transferring the hash.  But the limited key space of the PIN will still leave it vulnerable to brute force, and if you can't trust those who control the server then you don't have a trustworthy solution.

Comment: Would having a salt on the client side make things any different?

Comment: @AndreiPetrenko that would change the brute force attack requirements, but it would also require the server to trust the client to perform authentication, which is a non-starter.  The client should never be trusted.

Comment: Yep, if they control the server (I interpret as software wise, not just hardware-wise) they can intercept the pin no matter what. With hardware-only access it's still possible, but far harder. That just as an additional weakness on top of the key length

Answer (score 4):

A 6 digit PIN is a very weak protection, i.e. there are on average 500.000 attempts needed to guess it. Assuming that the attacker can try 1000 PIN's per second it would take on average 500 seconds to find the right PIN.

This means that the attacker must be severely slowed down in order to keep the PIN sufficiently secure. How much slow down is needed depends on how long the PIN need to be kept secret. For example if the attacker can only guess one PIN every minute it will **on average** need a year to guess the PIN, but of course the attacker can be a bit more lucky and guess the PIN faster.

But if the PIN is only valid for a short time anyway it might be possible to sufficiently slow down the attacker. Use cases are for example a PIN for a password reset, a TAN to confirm a transaction etc. If such PIN's are valid for some minutes only it might be possible to sufficiently slow down the attacker.

Slowing down the attacker must be done in a way that the valid user has still a chance to use the PIN within the limited time. Just limiting the number of tries per time at the server side might cause the attacker to quickly exhaust all tries, thereby essentially denying access to the valid user (i.e. a denial of service attack).

Therefore the slowdown should be enforced for each client separately. Assuming that it is impossible to reliable detect different users before each guess the slowdown should be better enforced at the client side. Since the server has no actual control over the clients the approach might be instead to require some
[Proof of Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work) like a [Client puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_Puzzle_Protocol). This way the client needs to invest sufficient computing resources (which at the end means time and money) to solve some problem first - the valid client (knowing the PIN) only once, while the attacker many more times. Such approaches are for example used or proposed as bot protection with [hashcash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash).

Of course such a solution needs lots of tuning - the complexity of the problem slows down the attacker considerably but will slow down a valid user (a bit) too. Very significant is the total time the client has, i.e. a few minutes might be fine while multiple days will be too much. If the 6-digit PIN protects only a low value the attacker will quickly give up, but if it protects a high value the attacker might employ many powerful resources even if these are expensive. And making the PIN even a bit longer or adding letters in addition to numbers can have make the problem significantly harder for the attacker even though it does not significantly downgrade the usability for the valid user. And additionally limiting the number of total tries will also help, like resetting the PIN after 1000 failed attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Usually users can accept only relatively short delay to check passwords or PINs, like 1 second. Thus you will have to configure PBKDF2 so that it takes not longer than 1 second. For a 6-digit PIN there are 1 000 000 values possible. To brute-force them an attacker would need 1 000 000 seconds on a single CPU. On the 10-core CPU it will take 100 000 seconds, which is about 1 day.

Thus brute-forcing will be very easy.

Comment: If you only rely on the password check CPU usage to slow things down you're just opening the door to DoS attacks on the server.

Comment: @jcaron: That is what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

A 4 digit PIN code is generaly seen as secure *provided it is used to unlock a local secure device*. And passing for 4 to 6 will not change that very much. To prevent brute force attack, you could imagine a TPM server side where a secret key would be unlocked by the PIN code. But the problem would be to prevent someone with admin privilege on server to *intercept* the code at the moment it is passed to the TPM because it will be in clear text at that time.

Whatever you do, you cannot protect data on a server against the admins of that server, unless the data is never decoded on that server. The rule is that you cannot protect a system against its admins.

Comment: If you can not protect data from admins - why bother i. e. salting passwords at all? And how did PIN verification work for bank cards before they had chips on them (the magnetic strip ones)?

Comment: Salting is used to protect passwords *at rest*, if an external attacker manages to access the passwords. But a regular (but rogue) admin has the ability to replace the full password library with one that could intercept the clear text version. Said differently it is an additional defense line,  hoping the attack to be identified before the attacker has passed them all.

Comment: But replacing the library will leave undeniable traces and will soon be detected, as opposing to sneakily dumping PIN hashes and brute-forcing PINs for sale as a hobby project.